# Do the physical iPad Pro devices return different Speech Synthesis Voices than their simulators?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, avfoundation, avspeechsynthesizer

I get a shorter list (returns a list of count 37) from 
`print(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices())` on the iPad 9.7" simulator than my actual 9.7" iPad (returns a list of count 52). They are running the same os (11.3) and the deployment target is the same for both builds.

I get the same short list for the iPad Pro 10 and 12 inch simulations. My question is do the physical iPad Pro devices return the shortened lists or the longer list that my physical 9.7" iPad returns?

In order to answer this all you need is an iPad Pro and to run in a view controller:

```
import AVFoundation
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().count)
}
```

in the simulator and on the physical device

Comment: I only have the 9.7" model and I'm curious if my device is the norm across all ipad devices: i.e. if I push my app to the app store how many voices will the ipad pro devices have access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this on a co-worker's iPad Pro today and indeed the physical device returned a count of 52 from `print(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().count)`